# Как указать в PHPDoc, что функция только может бросать исключения

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpdoc

Доброго времени суток. 
Есть функция, цель которой - обработка ошибки и генерация нужного исключения. Значений она возвращать не может, исключение выбрасывается в любом случае.

```
/**
 * @param VendorException $e
 * @throws BaseException
 */
private function handleException(VendorException $e)
{
    switch ($e->getCode()) {
        case 401:
            throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }

    throw new UnknownException($e->getMessage());
}
```

Есть функция, которая ее использует:

```
/**
 * @return string
 * @throws BaseException
 */
public function connect()
{
    try {
        $result = vendorConnect();
    } catch (VendorException $e) {
        $this->handleException($e);
    }

    return $result->data;
}
```

Возникает проблема, что, к примеру PHPStorm ругается, якобы $result может быть не определен (хотя до return выполнение не дойдет). Если слева от handleException добавить return, то будет ругаться на несовпадение возвращаемого значения (логично). Пустой return после обработки исключения, дает туже ошибку, да и выглядит как костыль.

Если есть возможность обойти это не выключая какие-либо проверки в IDE, жду совета :) Спасибо!

Comment: Странно но у меня всё нормально...

Comment: Какая у Вас версия штрома?

Comment: Можно инициализировать `$result = '';` вначале

Comment: Можно, это решает проблему "не инициализированной $result", но ведь тоже фактически костыль.

Comment: @PavelPol, Последняя: PhpStorm 2018.1 Build #PS-181.4203.565, built on March 28, 2018

Comment: можно задать тип перед использованием `/** @var FooBar $result */ $result` строкой выше над return

Comment: Как вариант, в `handleException` не бросать исключение, а возвращать объект нужного исключения (и переименовать в `getDetectedException`). А в `catch`  написать `throw $this->getDetectedException($e);`. Так и с точки зрения ООП логичнее

Comment: Спасибо, этот вариант мне нравится)